# How to remove folder and Its child pages from Google Search Index

Tags: seo, google-search, google-index

I am redesigning my site and It is located in sub folder of website directory. And Google have indexed our new site from sub folder which is affecting my search results of live site.

Is there any specific way, that I can remove sub folder from google search index and google search results ?

e.g. My Live site is www.xyz.com and 
I am redesigning on www.xyz.com/newsite

Is there anyway that I can remove /newsite from google search index and results ?

Comment: you'll need access to google webmaster tools!

Comment: Create a robots.txt and wait for the reindex

Comment: How much time google take to reindex or Its not possible to say ? Can we request google to remove specific directory and its pages to be removed from search index ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

Add this robots.txt file

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /newsite/
```

or best suited, get access to Google Webmaster

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal?hl=en&siteUrl=

add your website url after **=**

**For example:**

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal?hl=en&siteUrl=http://www.techplayce.com/

Comment: I do have access to google webmaster, But uder remove URL option, there is not any options to add diretory URL. Anyway, Does robots.txt works on indexed pages ?

Comment: What if I have two specific directories ?

Comment: Yes, it won't allow robots to crawl during next indexing.

Comment: copy paste `Disallow` line again and replace with new directory name there

Comment: Read this official documentation from Google, may it help you https://support.google.com/webmasters/topic/4598466?rd=1

Answer (score 0):

Yes by uploading robots.txt file on your site directory...
User-agent: *
Disallow: /newsite/
add this code if you have wordpress site then install a plugin for robots.txt